# Approximation Lemma for Riemann-integrable functions

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In the following let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be bounded functions.

For a [regulated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function), the integral could be written as the limit
$$
 \int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b \varphi_n(x) dx
$$
of a sequence $\varphi_n$ of step functions converging uniformly to $f$. Similar if $f$ is measurable, then there exists a sequence of simple functions $\varphi_n$ such that its Lebesgue-Integral could be written as
$$
  \int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b \varphi_n(x) dx.
$$

Now is there a similar convergence characterisation in terms of simpler functions for the Riemann-Integral? The closest I could think of is that $f$ is Riemann-integrable iff there exists sequences $\varphi_n, \psi_n$ of step functions such that 
$$
 \varphi_n \le f \le \psi_n \quad \mbox{and} \quad
 \int (\psi_n - \varphi_n) d x < \frac{1}{n}.
$$

Are there other characterisations or approximation formulations in terms of simpler functions in case $f$ is Riemann-integrable?

Comment: I imagine that you know Lebesgue characterization of Riemann-integrable functions?

Comment: Yes, a function is Riemann-integrable iff its set of discontinuities has measure zero, but I am looking more for some approximation by sequences.